# Linear combination of tensor products.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

In my Quantum Mechanics course, Tensor Products have been introduced , it is argued that they are vector spaces, but then while describing entanglement, it is argued that the Linear Combinations of tensor products cannot always be expressed as a single tensor product.But how is that possible? Isn't it a fact that any linear combination of vectors of a vector space can be expressed as a single vector?

Comment: Single vector in $V \otimes W$ vs single tensor product of the form $v \otimes w$. The former is a vector space containing the later, but has more too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same reason why not every matrix can be expressed in the form $A=uv^⊤$. The space of $m×n$ matrices is indeed the tensor-product $ℝ^m ⊗ (ℝ^n)^*$, i.e. every matrix can be written as a sum of ket-bras:

$$A = ∑_i |u_i⟩⟨v_i|  \;\hat{=}\; ∑_i u_i ⊗ v_i \;\hat{=}\; ∑_i u_i v_i^⊤ $$

But only rank-1 matrices can be written as pure tensors. By definition,  a tensor-space can be considered as the linear completion of the set of pure tensors.